# pandas sort values to get which item is placed with the most quantity

Tags: python, pandas

how to show which item is placed with the most quantity from this data?

how to show which item is most ordered groupby choice_description?

```
url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/justmarkham/DAT8/master/data/chipotle.tsv'
df= pd.read_csv(url, sep = '\t')
```

My data

```
order_id    quantity    item_name   choice_description  item_price
1   1   Chips and Fresh Tomato Salsa    NULL    $2.39 
1   1   Nantucket Nectar    [Apple] $3.39 
2   2   Chicken Bowl    [Tomatillo-Red Chili Salsa (Hot), [Black Beans, Rice, Cheese, Sour Cream]]  $16.98 
3   1   Chicken Bowl    [Fresh Tomato Salsa (Mild), [Rice, Cheese, Sour Cream, Guacamole, Lettuce]] $10.98 
3   1   Side of Chips   NULL    $1.69 
4   1   Steak Burrito   [Tomatillo Red Chili Salsa, [Fajita Vegetables, Black Beans, Pinto Beans, Cheese, Sour Cream, Guacamole, Lettuce]]  $11.75 
4   1   Steak Soft Tacos    [Tomatillo Green Chili Salsa, [Pinto Beans, Cheese, Sour Cream, Lettuce]]   $9.25 
...
...
```

Comment: IMHO the `choice_description` column is too messy so a direct groupby is practically meaningless. The OP must specify how to deal with this situation precisely, but that would be another question which is completely different from what was initially asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will list all ties (if any).

```
df.loc[df["quantity"] == df["quantity"].max(), "item_name"]
```

Output:

```
3598    Chips and Fresh Tomato Salsa
Name: item_name, dtype: object
```

Comment: and how to show which item is most ordered groupby choice_description? Thanks!

Comment: It can be done theoretically. However, your `choice_description` is not parsed and seem to require heavy cleansing before the result to be meaningful.  Please run `df.groupby("choice_description")["quantity"].max()` and see how messy the `choice_description` column is. You must specify how you want to deal with such situation precisely.

Answer (score 2):

- If you want to show all the data:

```py
df.sort_values('quantity', ascending=False)
```

Output:

```
order_id    quantity    item_name                     choice_descri item_price
1443        15          Chips and Fresh Tomato Salsa  NaN            $44.25
1660        10          Bottled Water                 NaN            $15.00
1559        8           Side of Chips                 NaN            $13.52
1443        7           Bottled Water                 NaN            $10.50
...
```

- If you want to show only the first row:

```py
df.sort_values('quantity', ascending=False).head(1)
```

Output:

```
order_id    quantity    item_name                     choice_descri item_price
1443        15          Chips and Fresh Tomato Salsa  NaN            $44.25
```

- Or if you want to show only the name:

```py
df.sort_values('quantity', ascending=False).head(1).item_name
```

```
3598    Chips and Fresh Tomato Salsa
Name: item_name, dtype: object
```

Comment: it work but it show all of data from df and name is not displayed. How to show only top row?

Comment: Try this: df.sort_values('quantity', ascending=False).head(1) to show all the row or df.sort_values('quantity', ascending=False).head(1).item_name to show only the name.

Comment: In  'df.sort_values('quantity', ascending=False).head(1).item_name'  What does the number 3598 mean?

Comment: If you don't define an index column when you read the csv, pandas creates one: it is the position of the element, like the row number. You can access directly to this row:
df.iloc[3598]

Answer (score 0):

Item with most quantity -
`chipo.groupby(['item_name'])['quantity'].sum().sort_values(ascending=False).index.values[0]`

Most ordered groupby choice -
`chipo.groupby(['choice_description'])['quantity'].sum().sort_values(ascending=False).index.values[0]`